# Mongodb | TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

It worked earlier, I simply switched out the names of 'server/routes/api.js' to 'server/routes/capture.js'
And it is now giving this error.
How is it giving undefinded?

This is the whole error:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/server/routes/capture.js:3
    router.post('/captures', function(req, res){
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
    at module.exports (/home/ubuntu/workspace/server/routes/capture.js:3:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:31:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

My code:

server/routes/capture.js

```
var Capture = require('../models/capture');
module.exports = function(router) {
    router.post('/captures', function(req, res){
        var capture = new Capture();
        capture.birdname = req.body.birdname;
        capture.place.city = req.body.place.city;
        capture.place.country = req.body.place.country;

        capture.save(function(err, data){
            if(err)
                throw err;
            console.log(req.body);
            res.json(data);
        });
    });

    router.get('/captures', function(req, res){
        Capture.find({}, function(err, data){
            res.json(data);
        });
    });

    router.delete('/captures', function(req, res){
        Capture.remove({}, function(err){
            res.json({result: err ? 'error' : 'ok'});
        });
    });

    router.get('/captures/:id', function(req, res){
        Capture.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, data){
            res.json(data);
        });
    });

    router.delete('/captures/:id', function(req, res){
        Capture.remove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err){
            res.json({result: err ? 'error' : 'ok'});
        });
    });

    router.post('/captures/:id', function(req, res){
        Capture.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, data){
            var capture = data;
            capture.birdname = req.body.birdname;
            capture.place.city = req.body.place.city;
            capture.place.country = req.body.place.country;

            capture.save(function(err, data){
                if(err)
                    throw err;
                res.json(data);
            });
        })
    })
}
```

server/models/capture.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var captureSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    birdname: String,
    place: {
        city: String,
        country: String   
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Capture', captureSchema)
```

server/config/database.js

```
module.exports = {
    'url': "mongodb://[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]@ds032579.mlab.com:32579/birdspotter"
}
```

server.js

```
// Init Express Web Framework
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

// Set view engine to EJS & set views directory
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'views'));

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client')));

// Database Connection
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var configDB = require('./server/config/database.js');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Main route
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

// API 
var api = express.Router();
require('./server/routes/capture')(api);
app.use('/api', api);

// Set routes to other pages
app.get('/*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

// Port Settings
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP);
console.log('Listening on port ' + process.env.PORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your capture file is not being passed Route. You can verify that by console logging route in your file and it will return undefined. One way of accessing router in a route file is as follows:

in app:

```
var capture = require('./capture');
app.use('/capture', capture);
```

in capture.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),

module.exports = function(alertService) {

    router.use(sanitize.facilityIds);

    router.post('/', function(req, res) {
        // your code here
    });
    return router;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with `findOne()` function of Mongo. `findOne()` is deprecated in newer versions of Mongo. Instead, try using:
`find().item(1)`